# Исчерпан лимит запросов

Tags: yandex-geocoding-api

Сегодня в личном кабинете обнаружил, что исчерпан лимит запросов. При этом я уверен, что условия бесплатного использования выполнялись, т.к приложение еще в разработке. В статистике использования тоже нули. С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: С тем, что Ваша уверенность базируется на недостоверных данных.

Comment: Вы перепутали ruSO и техподдержку яндекса

Comment: Что вам мешает создать новый аккаунт, если использование бесплатное?

Comment: Вам правда нужно написать в техподдержку, сообщив свой ключ. На SO с таким вопросом не помогут